# Multiple cell criteria conditional formatting in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, multiple-conditions

Two Conditional formatting Formula Questions:

How to create a conditional formatting formula that:

1. checks to see if anything is in Column O
2. if blank, then check to see if date in column J is greater than TODAYs date
3. if yes, then highlight cell in Column J and highlight column/cell B & A

if 1) has something in Column O then the formatting stops altogether.

How to create a conditional formatting formula that:

1. Looks at date in Column I and if earlier than TODAYs date then
2. Looks at Column J and Column O, if both empty, then
3. Highlight Column I, Column/cell B & A

if 1) is not earlier, then nothing happens

I can create a conditional formula that just highlights based off a date, but not associated with the contents of another cell and highlighting other cell not in the comparison based on the outcome

Answer (score 0):

**First CF :**

Range **A1:B999,J1:J999**

Custom Formula:

```
=AND(ISBLANK($O1),DATEVALUE(TODAY())<DATEVALUE($J1))
```

**Second CF :**

Range **A1:B999,I1:I999**

Custom Formula:

```
=AND(ISBLANK($O1),ISBLANK($J1),DATEVALUE(TODAY())>DATEVALUE($I1))
```

It gives me something like this :
[image: example]

I hope this helps!